# Referencing 128-bit values at address

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

How do I reference 128-bit values at an address?

I tried `ADDPD XMM0, QUADWORD PTR [0x11223344]` but it says `junk PTR [0x11223344] after expression`. I know quadwords work like in `ADDSD`.

I'm using this [Online x86 / x64 Assembler and Disassembler](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly)

Comment: Try `ADDPD XMM0, [0x11223344]`.

Comment: A quad word is 64-bits and is spelled QWORD. 128-bit values are OWORD.

Comment: The register operand should be enough info for the assembler to deduce the size.